# localhost/Laravel/public - notfoundhttpexception error

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I am trying to output a very basic program which says 'hello world'

My web.php

```
<? php

Route::get('/',function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

My `welcome.blade.php` file

```
{{ 'Hello World' }}
```

The `welcome.blade.php` is inside the views folder, but when I give `localhost/laravel/public/` I am getting an error stating `"The page you're looking for cannot be found"`

Please Help me out.

Comment: Try echo in your route file function.

Comment: run this command `php artisan serve` and browse `localhost:8000` then see what happens

Comment: @SmitRaval I tried that. I am thrown with the same exception

Comment: @Sohel0415 I did that too. Still getting the same error

Comment: Which server are you using? @Raghunathan

Comment: Did you just setup new server?

Comment: @SmitRaval I am using WAMP. I already had it set up a few months ago. It was working fine. Yesterday I created a new model, migration and a controller. After that it's not working. I tried clearing the route cache, I deleted the controllers, models and migrations. Still not working

Comment: @SmitRaval Only the public directory is not working. When I go to the "welcome.blade.php" directory like this 
http://localhost/Laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php its working

Comment: Check my answer below, follow steps and let me know if it works? @Raghunathan

Comment: Do you have any other route in web.php? And what else do you have in welcom.blade.php file beside `{{ 'Hello world' }}`

Comment: @Ahsan I have nothing other than that in welcome.blade.php

Comment: I think you need to put basic HTML tags including HTML, title and body... I suggest you to keep the default welcome.blade.php file and open it. then you can modify the file as you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `laravel new hello-world-laravel` or `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel hello-world-laravel`
3. Type `cd hello-world-laravel`
4. Type `php artisan serve`
5. Open browser to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
6. Open project in IDE, I used sublime text.
7. Edit welcome.blade.php
8. Save Edits.
9. Open browser to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Here are those exact steps in action. Up in running in less than 30 seconds.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-images/hello-world-laravel.gif

The route `Route::get('/',function() { ...` in `web.php` is using a laravel [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-view) to render the blade template.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-view

Comment: I don't understand, I am a beginner. Can you please explain it to me in simple terms ?

Comment: I suggest you start with reading the documentation then: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation

Comment: better read the docs, ahhh, they start there... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installing-laravel or type `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel hello-world-laravel`

Comment: Oh I am sorry , got it

Comment: I required all the files , but when I run PHP artisan serve , it says autoload.php not found

Answer (score 0):

Try this.You can remove public directory from your url.

> 1. Rename your server.php file to index.php file in root
> 2. Move .htaccess file from public directory to root

Access your url like

> localhost/laravel/

Check if it works?

Comment: Throwing the same exception :/

Comment: Where did you created a folder laravel in xamp?

Comment: Show me the path of the folder please.

Comment: I am using wamp. I created the folder Laravel in
C:\wamp\www\Laravel

Comment: You have a capital L in your folder name. Try with localhost/Laravel

Comment: I have been using capital L all this while. I don't think that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the built in server or
2. WAMP or MAMP or XAMPP

**How to use the built in server ?**
**Windows :**

Download the git bash or equivalent application. This is easy to execute unix commands.

**Linux or Mac :**
Open the terminal and browse to the folder where the laravel project exist.

eg) cd D:/Desktop/laravel/blog

Type `php artisan serve --port 9000`
You could see the message as below

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:9000

Now browse `http://127.0.0.1:9000/ or http://localhost:9000/`

Laravel default page should be visible now. Now you can modify the welcome blade file. After refresh the browser page, it shows the changes what you made.

**XAMPP or wamp**

Install the fresh laravel applicaton inside the htdocs (xampp) or relevant root directory.

Start the apache and mysql server from wamp or xampp server.

Browse to `localhost:80/laravel/blog` => here blog is the laravel application available inside laravel folder